# Issue while enabling prometheus monitoring in azure k8s

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, prometheus

Getting error while configuring prometheus in azure kubernetes

[image]

Comment: Is your cluster set to use a service principal instead of a managed identity?

Comment: Now sure about it if yes then how to fix this @CSharpRocks

Answer (score 1):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

*I have the cluster and I am trying to configure the Prometheus in azure Kubernetes and I got the successful deployment*

[image]

*To verify the agent is deployed or not use the below commands*

```
 kubectl get ds <dep_name> --namespace=kube-system
 kubectl get rrs --namespace=kube-system
```

[image]

*This error getting because of you are using the service principal instead of managed identity*

*For enabling the managed identity please follow the below commands*

*AKS cluster with service principal first disable monitoring and then upgrade to managed identity, the azure public cloud is supporting  for this migration*

*To get the log analytics workspace id*

```
az aks show -g <rg_name> -n <cluster_name> | grep -i "logAnalyticsWorkspaceResourceID"
```

For disable the monitoring use the below command

```
az aks disable-addons -a monitoring -g <rg_name> -n <cluster_name>
```

*Or I can get it on portal in the azure monitor logs*

[image]

*I have upgrade the cluster to system managed identity, use the below command to upgrade*

```
az aks update -g <rg_name> -n <cluster_name> --enable-managed-identity
```

[image]

*I have enable the monitoring addon with the managed identity authentication*

```
az aks enable-addons -a monitoring --enable-msi-auth-for-monitoring -g <rg_name> -n <cluster_name> --workspace-resource-id <workspace_resource_id>
```

*For more information use this document for [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-enable-aks?tabs=azure-cli#migrate-to-managed-identity-authentication)*